# How can I start Fedora Directory Service with SELinux enabled?

Tags: linux, selinux, 389-ds, fedora

I just did a fresh base install of fedora 12, and did a yum install 389-ds. I went through the included setup script (setup-ds-admin.pl) and everything started fine and was working normally. I could access the directory server and login using the directory manager account created during the setup.

After a reboot I tried starting the dirsrv service using the following command:

```
[root@test-ds ~]# /etc/init.d/dirsrv-admin start
Starting dirsrv-admin:                                  [  OK  ]
[root@test-ds ~]# /etc/init.d/dirsrv start
Starting dirsrv: 
test-ds...
[26/Feb/2010:14:59:11 -0500] dse - The entry cn=config in file
/etc/dirsrv/slapd-test-ds/dse.ldif is invalid, error code 53
(DSA is unwilling to perform) - nsslapd-errorlog-mode: Failed to chmod
error log file to 600: errno 1 (Operation not permitted)

[26/Feb/2010:14:59:11 -0500] dse - Could not load config file [dse.ldif]
[26/Feb/2010:14:59:11 -0500] dse - Please edit the file to correct the
reported problems and then restart the server.
                                                           [FAILED]
  *** Warning: 1 instance(s) failed to start
```

If I turn off SELinux with "setenforce 0", it can start without any issue. There are no entries generated in /var/log/audit/audit.log like I'd normally see for an SELinux error but it's infinitely repeatable turning SELinux on and off with setenforce.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a [known bug](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=545771).

Try updating your [SELinux Policy](http://www.mail-archive.com/fedora-package-announce@redhat.com/msg32876.html) to minimum 3.6.32-59.

Comment: Thanks that was it! I tried searching for known bugs but I didn't stumble across this one because I assumed it would still be marked as 'open'. Oh well, Thanks again!